# craftsman shop vac motor stuck on reverse

Tags: electric-motor

Apparently the motor itself is reversed. It I'd blowing out the top hole.

I cannot find any " reverse" switch cm and I doubt it has one. It apparently got switched into reverse somehow and I need to reset it.

It is a Craftsman 9 gallon (red) .

Any advice?

Comment: how old is it? Maybe the hose goes on the other hole on the side???

Answer (score 1):

I'm just tunnel-visioned. I was sure I had plugged it into the correct socket, but no.

Stupid User Trick

Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the ball is not stuck inside the housing. It SCHOULD be lose when machine is off completely. always try a different outlet to eliminate that. Then inspect the cord a new plug possibly installed backwards or a cut and repair or even a slice out of the cord. Could cause a motor reversal.

Comment: the cord on AC would not reverse the motor.

Comment: Only thing that changes the rotation on a universal motor is the commutator brush position. Often not changeable and must be disassembled if it is..

Comment: It's a good excuse to check those things.